# Routing from user location to POI in pgRouting?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po, postgresql-10

I have roads(edge) table and hospitals(point of interest) table in pgRouting database.

Now I want to take user location or any point location that user inputs as a **starting node** and **ending node** must be a hospital location

How can I do this?

Comment: did you try what I suggested in your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/285784/93656)? the *withPoints* function family is your best bet at this, and this is basically the usecase for what that other question aims at solving.

Comment: Yes I did but I am confused with start_vid and end_vid parameters, I want start_vid as user desired location not the POI.